# Jail user to only read/write into their user directory

Tags: ubuntu, directory, users, home-directory, jail

I'm running a Ubuntu server and wanted to know if there was a way to only allow a user (connecting via FTP and SSH) read and write access to their own /home/*user*/ directory and not let them read or write to anything else?

Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a [chroot jail for FTP on Ubuntu](http://beginlinux.com/blog/2009/10/ubuntu-9-10-chroot-jail-for-ftp/) HowTo which should cover your requirements for FTP - securing your server for SSH users is a more complicated topic and will really depend upon what you want your users to be able to do (by default, file ownership and permissions will prevent users from altering files they don't own, but allowing users SSH access **and** allowing them to broadcast their passwords in plaintext over FTP is not ideal).

Comment: Awesome! How did I miss that from the config :)